# Create parent-children tree-like array of objects from ordered array of strings with their relationship in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

I have an array of objects, where each object has a property (`parentsList`) indicating the category the current item belongs to, something like:

```
const data = [
    {
        ...other properties,
        "parentsList": [
            "Assets",
            "Icons"
        ],
    },
    {
        ...other properties,
        "parentsList": [
            "Assets",
            "Fonts"
        ],
    },
   {
      ...other properties,
       "parentsList": [
            "Programming",
            "JavaScript",
            "Docs"
        ],
   },
   {
      ...other properties,
       "parentsList": [
            "Programming",
            "JavaScript",
            "React",
            "Libraries",
        ],
   },
]
```

That means the first object belongs to `assets/icons`, the second to `assets/fonts`, third to `programming/javascript/docs`  and so on.

I'm trying to map it to a tree-like view, where siblings should be under the same parent, something like:

```js
const data = [
    {
        name: 'Assets',
        id: 'assets',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'Icons',
                id: 'assets/icons',
            },
            {
                name: 'Illustrations',
                id: 'assets/illustrations',
            },
        ],
    },
    {
        name: 'Programming',
        id: 'programming',
        children: [
            {
                name: 'JavaScript',
                id: 'programming/javascript',
                children: [
                    {
                        name: 'Docs',
                        id: 'programming/javascript/docs',
                    },
                    {
                        name: 'React',
                        id: 'programming/javascript/react',
                        children: [
                            {
                                name: 'Libraries',
                                id: 'programming/javascript/react/libraries',
                            },
                        ],
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
]
```

I imagine it's gonna be easier to traverse from the right, maybe with `reduceRight()`, but I can't seem to get it right.

Anyone would know how to achieve that?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not use an actual tree data structure instead?

Comment: what happens to *"other properties"*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to avoid using `reduce` because I find it difficult to read the code that has `reduce` in it. So, here is a `non-reduce` way.

```js
const data = [
    {
        parentsList: [
            "Assets",
            "Icons"
        ],
    },
    {
        parentsList: [
            "Assets",
            "Fonts"
        ],
    },
    {
        parentsList: [
            "Programming",
            "JavaScript",
            "Docs"
        ],
    },
    {
        parentsList: [
            "Programming",
            "JavaScript",
            "React",
            "Libraries",
        ],
    },
];

const processedData = [];

for (const item of data) {
    const parents = [...item.parentsList].reverse();
    let children = processedData;
    const ids = [];
    while (parents.length > 0) {
        const parent = parents.pop();
        ids.push(parent.toLowerCase());
        let foundParent = false;
        for (const child of children) {
            if (child.name === parent) {
                children = child.children;
                foundParent = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (!foundParent) {
            const newChild = {name: parent, id: ids.join("/"), children: [],};
            children.push(newChild);
            children = newChild.children;
        }
    }
}

console.log(processedData);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as a combination of `forEach` and `reduce` and create a nested hierarchy based on the `parentsList` array.

```js
const data = [{"parentsList":["Assets","Icons"]},{"parentsList":["Assets","Fonts"]},{"parentsList":["Programming","JavaScript","Docs"]},{"parentsList":["Programming","JavaScript","React","Libraries"]}]

const result = []

data.forEach(function({ parentsList, ...rest }) {
  let id = '';

  parentsList.reduce((r, name, i) => {
    id += (id.length ? '/' : '') + name.toLowerCase();

    if (!r[name]) {
      const value = { id, name }
      r[name] = {result: []}

      if (i != parentsList.length - 1) {
        value.children = r[name].result
      } else {
        Object.assign(value, rest)
      }

      r.result.push(value)
    }

    return r[name]
  }, this)

}, {result})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

A short approach by using nested objects as hash tables.

```js
const
    data = [{ parentsList: ["Assets", "Icons"] }, { parentsList: ["Assets", "Fonts"] }, { parentsList: ["Programming", "JavaScript", "Docs"] }, { parentsList: ["Programming", "JavaScript", "React", "Libraries"] }],
    tree = data.reduce((t, { parentsList }) => {
        parentsList.reduce((r, name, i, a) => {
            const id = a.slice(0, i + 1).join('/').toLowerCase();
            if (!r[name]) {
                r[name] = { _: { name, id } };
                (r._.children ??= []).push(r[name]._);
            }
            return r[name];
        }, t);
        return t;
    }, { _: {} })._.children;

console.log(tree);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```